# No Freighters getting attacked in Blighted Expedition

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm trying to play the Blighted Expedition, but I'm stuck on the Liberation goal on Phase 1.  It says to warp to different systems, find freighter groups, and save them from pirate attack.  I have warped to three different systems, found freighters at all the space stations, but none of them are getting attacked by pirates, except one maybe, but it happened while I was on a planet and by the time I got there there was no sign of pirates.

I have been attacked by pirates three times but no freighters have.  Am I doing something wrong?  How do   I complete this mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed this part of the Expedition.

I warped some more and ended up warping right into an ongoing pirate/freighter fight, which leads me to believe that you shouldn't waste time waiting for one to occur.  I think you are supposed to warp around until you find one immediately.

Comment: IIRC, you are guaranteed to find an attacked freighter each 5 warps if you played at least 3 hours since the last one.

Comment: Good to know.  thnx